# Mongoose search data by object

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make a search in database by JSON objects.

Here is my schema:

```
var patientSchema = new Schema({
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
age: String,
tel: String,

work: [workSchema],

});
```

My angular js request, sends an JSON object which will be:

```
{'firstname':'value', 'lastname':'value', 'age':'age','tel':tel}
```

Is there a way to search for the matches directly in the Patient Schema?
so if the JSON object contains only firstname value .. it will check that

in MySQL I would do,

```
SELECT * FROM patients WHERE firstname LIKE '%'.json.firstname AND .....
```

what I've tested is

```
var filter = "{'firstname': 'value', 'lastname': 'value', 'age':'value', 'tel': 'tel'}" //sent from angularjs client

var jsonFilter = JSON.parse(filter);

Patient.find().or([
        { 'firstname': { $regex: new RegExp(filter.firstname,'i') }},
        { 'lastname': { $regex: new RegExp(filter.lastname,'i')  }},
        { 'age':{ $regex: new RegExp(filter.age,'i')  }},
        { 'tel':{$regex: new RegExp(filter.tel,'i')  }}]).exec(function(err, result) {

        if ( err)
            throw err;

        res.json(result);
    });
```

this works fine but ALL the data should be filled if the attributes are empty it will return undefined which will not get me the right data. since Angular JS sends only the $scope.data.

Is there a way to get all the data by my JSON object, and not rewriting all the JSON fields, because I need to make bigger filters in this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it is the best way to do this, but it is a start. I would loop over your keys and build your query dynamically. By looping over your keys, you can add as many keys as you want. For each key, push your new regex to your query variable. Finally, use your result as query.

Here is the code:

```
var filter = {'firstname': 'value', 'lastname': 'value', 'age':'value', 'tel': 'tel'};
var query = {$or: []};
var keys = Object.keys(filter);

for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    var item = {};
    item[keys[i]] = new RegExp(filter[key], 'i');
    query.$or.push(item);
}

Patient.find(query).exec(function(err, result) {
    if ( err)
        throw err;

    res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: thank you this might do the trick i will test but i think it should be fine

Comment: the only problem in here is  {key: new RegExp(filter[key], 'i')}
the first key remains "key" in the loop it doesn't get it value, but
filter[key] works normally so the query deosn't find anything don't know if its mongoose issue ?

Comment: @Kiu I don't think I understand your problem because _key_ is not printed as the String "key" but as the actual key in your object...

Comment: actually yes it is, it deosn't get the value but it prints the string but filter[key] works fine .
this is what i get when i console.log the query

{ '$or' : [ { key : /John/i } , { key: /doe/i } ] }

Comment: @Kiu Strange. I have edited my answer and it is working now!

Comment: item[keys[i]] = new RegExp(filter[keys[i]], 'i'); and it works fine thank you